# Is there value/purpose in declaring a pattern ^(.*)$ for JSON properties of type string?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm learning REST webservices and I've been assigned the task of wrapping (creating a new JSON schema on top of) an existing REST API for which I have been given its JSON schema. The schema that I am wrapping specifies a `"pattern": "^(.*)$"` for properties (such as *city* or *streetAddress*) that are of `"type": "string"`. The regex matches everything until a line terminator is encountered. I know that the REST API that I am wrapping in turn wraps a SOAP message (and may have been mechanically converted from SOAP to JSON - so I suspect a conversion artifact is at work here).

My question is, is this a typical pattern to apply to strings passed to and from webservice endpoints or is it's specificity redundant and unnecessary?

My thought is that the generation of this pattern within the JSON schema is an artifact of the automated conversion process and as such it would make sense to simplify my wrapper by omitting the `"pattern": "^(.*)$"`.

Comment: Is it used to ensure the properties are just one line?

Comment: @axblount—newlines in JSON must  be escaped anyway, so no, it doesn't ensure properties are one line (as JSON.parse will restore the newlines).

Answer (score 3):

I would make an informed guess that someone has previously taken a JSON instance, and used a tool to generate some or all of the JSON Schema files you are looking at.

I couldn't tell you why they have done this, but it seems pretty pointless.
It could be to make sure there are no line breaks in each of those fields, but I've also seen this in generated schemas more than a few times.

Comment: I have come to the same conclusion and as such I am freeing myself from the constraints of the implementation that I've inherited - thanks to all for your time and consideration!

Comment: It would be great if you could accept my answer. Thanks.